# How to add a Fade In effect for images in HTML

Tags: html, css, image, effects

**Source**

```
  <div style="position:absolute; left: 700px; top:200px;">
      <img id="obj1" src="https://www.instagram.com/static/images/homepage/screenshots/screenshot2.png/4d62acb667
  </div>
```

**Timer to change the Images every 5 seconds**

```
      <script type="text/javascript">
          const images = ["https://www.instagram.com/static/images/homepage/screenshots/screenshot2.png/4d62acb667fb.png", "https://www.instagram.com/static/images/homepage/screenshots/screenshot4.png/a4fd825e3d49.png", "https://www.instagram.com/static/images/homepage/screenshots/screenshot1.png/fdfe239b7c9f.png", "https://www.instagram.com/static/images/homepage/screenshots/screenshot3.png/94edb770accf.png"]
          const image = document.getElementById("obj1");
          let currentImage = 0
          function volgendefoto() {
              image.src = images[currentImage];
              currentImage += 1;
              let amountOfImages = images.length
              if (currentImage == images.length) {
                  currentImage = 0
              }
          }
          setInterval(volgendefoto, 5000);
      </script>
```

**Do I need to download all images and make a different source instead of links?**

Comment: Could you clarify the question. Are you asking how to not only change the image every 5 seconds, but to make the change gradual so the new image comes in from opacity 0 to opacity 1? If so, how long do you want the changing of opacity to take? And do you want the previous image to fade out?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Animate.css for your project.

https://animate.style/

Install the library like this:

`npm install animate.css --save`

If you don't use npm you can import it like this:

```
<head>
  <link
    rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/4.1.1/animate.min.css"
  />
</head>
```

And you can uses the class of the library like this:

```
 <div style="position:absolute; left: 700px; top:200px;">
      <img class="animate__fadeIn" id="obj1" src="https://www.instagram.com/static/images/homepage/screenshots/screenshot2.png/4d62acb667
  </div>
```